# Powershell set-location on custom provider works fine on console but not as a script

Tags: powershell

**EDIT
it was an error my end oops none of the information here would of been able to help solve it long story short the oauth token was expired when I ran the script**

I've made a custom powershell provider if I run this through the powershell console it works fine:

```
PS C:\Users\foo.bar> add-pssnapin Pacme
PS C:\Users\foo.bar>
PS C:\Users\foo.bar> $token = set-token -clientId fileadminprojectacmeoob
Please Enter the Auth code into the console!
*removed*
PS C:\Users\foo.bar>
PS C:\Users\foo.bar> new-psdrive -psprovider Pacme -name myacme -root "" -Host api.acme.dev -token $token

*provider gets created no point showing this just takes up space*


PS C:\Users\foo.bar> cd myacme:/
PS myacme:\>
```

however if I run this as a script

```
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'myacme:\' because it does not exist.
At C:\scripts\entry.ps1:20 char:3
+ cd <<<<  myacme:
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (myacme:\:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand


PS C:\scripts>
```

does anyone know why cd myAcme: works fine in the console but not as a script?

Answer (score 0):

it was an error my end oops none of the information here would of been able to help solve it long story short the token would expiry by the time the script ran